# How to restrict lines by intersections with other lines pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have three lines drawn as `\addplot` functions in pgfplots. I want to restrict the domain of the lines based on their intersections. In the picture, I want to:

1. plot the red line only between the black curves.
2. plot the dashed line from 0 to the red curve.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={%
        width=6cm,
        xmin=0,xmax=1,
        xtick={0,0.1,...,1}},
    ymin=0,ymax=1, enlarge x limits=false,
    ytick={0,0.2,...,1}}
%
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1,range=0:1,samples=100]
    \addplot[name path global=line2,mark=none,red] {(2*.0105 - (x*.055 + .03)*(1-.8)) / (.0105 + x*.055*(1-.8^40))};  
    \addplot[name path global=line1,mark=none] {(.0105 + x*.055*(.8 - .8^40) - .03*(1-.8)) / ( .0105 + x*.055*(.8 - .8^40))  };  
    \addplot[name path global=line3,mark=none,black,dashed] {(.055*x*(1-.8)) / .0105};  
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Line Plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clip `line2` and `line3` inside a rectangle with corners `(0,0)` and `A-|B`,  where points `A` and `B` define intersection of `line1` with `line2` and `line`2 with `line3` respectively

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={%
    width=6cm,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    xtick={0,0.1,...,1}},
ymin=0,ymax=1, enlarge x limits=false,
ytick={0,0.2,...,1}}
%
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:1,range=0:1,samples=100]
\addplot[name path global=line1,mark=none] {(.0105 + x*.055*(.8 - .8^40) - .03*(1-.8)) / ( .0105 + x*.055*(.8 - .8^40))  };  
\addplot[name path global=line2,draw=none] {(2*.0105 - (x*.055 + .03)*(1-.8)) / (.0105 + x*.055*(1-.8^40))};
\addplot[name path global=line3,draw=none] {(.055*x*(1-.8)) / .0105};  

\begin{scope}
\path [name intersections={of=line1 and line2,by=A}];
\path [name intersections={of=line2 and line3,by=B}];
\path[clip](0,0)rectangle(A-|B);
\addplot[name path global=line2,mark=none,red] {(2*.0105 - (x*.055 + .03)*(1-.8)) / (.0105 + x*.055*(1-.8^40))};
\addplot[name path global=line3,mark=none,black,dashed] {(.055*x*(1-.8)) / .0105};  
\end{scope}  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]